# Entity update causes error: cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-5.x

I have following table entities, In that I am trying update an existing record, while doing so i get following error. I know I'm doing some mistake in the entity definition but not able to figure it out.
Appreciate your help.

```
                **A
        -------------------
        |                 |
        B                 C
                      ---------
                      |       |
                      D       E**

@Entity
@Table()
public class A {
    @Id
    Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName="id",  nullable = false)
    private Set<B> b;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName="ID",  nullable = false)  
    private Set<C> c;
}

@Entity
@Table()
public class B{
    @Id
    Long id;
}

@Entity
@Table()
public class C{
    @Id
    Long id;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName="id",  nullable = false)
    private Set<D> D;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName="ID",  nullable = false)  
    private Set<E> E;
}

@Entity
@Table()
public class D{
    @Id
    Long id;
}

@Entity
@Table()
public class E{
    @Id
    Long id;
}
```

ERROR:

org.hibernate.HibernateException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: com.entity.C.D

```
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections.processDereferencedCollection(Collections.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections.processUnreachableCollection(Collections.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushCollections(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:262) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
```

Answer (score 4):

- In save mode, just set the list to the entity and it works.

  - `operation:` save
  - `method`: set
- But in the update mode, you must first clear the current list of entity and then add the updated list to it, do not use set method in update mode.

  - `operation`: update
  - `methods`: clear, add

---

**in save mode**

```
person.setAddresses(addressList);
```

**in update mode**

```
person.getAddresses().clear();
person.getAddresses().addAll(updatedAddressList);
```

Answer (score 3):

The mapping depends of the ownership of association, considering your example, it's difficult to point out, but you can check this [post](https://thoughts-on-java.org/best-practices-many-one-one-many-associations-mappings/) to understand better when use one or another approach and the consequences in the database. I don't know if this is the case of your update, but when you update the childs you need to clear your past collection and use the addAll method to avoid this kind of error. Check this [post](http://cristian.sulea.net/blog/hibernate-exception-a-collection-with-cascade-all-delete-orphan-was-no-longer-referenced-by-the-owning-entity-instance/) as well.